# How can I manipulate a String in a JSF tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

Given this code,

```html
<rich:dataTable id="list" value="#{testBeen.dataModel}" var="test" rows="#{testBeen.dataModel.pageSize}">
    ...
    <h:outputText value="#{test.WEEK}" />
```

I need to manipulate the `#{test.WEEK}` and replace character `)` with `]`, how can I do this?

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
<%String a = test.WEEK; a.replace("a", "b"); %>
<%=a %>
```

How can I get the string from JSF and pass it back to JSF?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this particular simple purpose, I'd just use the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib. There's a [`fn:replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) function.

E.g.

```html
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(test.WEEK, ')', ']')}" />
```

You should for sure **never** use *scriptlets* `<% %>` in JSF pages.

Comment: and for xhtml, you can just add it to the html tag like xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" too. It's a great resource ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could write a custom Converter and parameterize it by search and replace string.
See this introduction [JSF for nonbelievers: JSF conversion and validation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf3/)

Answer (score 0):

Good practice would be to do this in the bean rather than the facelet.