# How to "hide" the last part of the text in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am using primefaces datatable to show some data and I would like to limit the text shown to the user. I have a description that contains hundreds of lines, but I don't want to show more than 50 characters in the datatable before the user taps that row. How can I do this? I searched the JSF Api, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901875/how-can-i-manipulate-a-string-in-a-jsf-tag/7902538#7902538) you could use the JSTL function `substring` for this purpose:

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<h:outputText value="#{fn:substring(yourBean.text, 0, 49)}" />
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I actually looked at the function in the book and probably didn't read it properly =)

Comment: You should prepare your self something call "description". Some ridiculous situation i met when substring, casuse the misunderstood (English not my mothertougle so i don't know any example in English about this situation :| ).

Comment: Note that using JSTL fn:substring(), it is not necessary to check the string length. If too small, this does not give a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - unlike String.substring().

Answer (score 1):

There are few suggestions on **shrinking data**:

1- *InputText's maxlength attribute*, javadoc says:

> Maximum number of characters that may be entered in this field.

But I am not sure if it will shrink data which goes from server-side rather than client-side.

2- Another suggestion is getting from *shortened value from server-side* backing bean.

And few on **expanding data**:

1. If it is JSF 2.0, use out of box *ajax functions*, it has it , not sure about PrimeFaces.
2. If it is JSF1.2 (or higher) I would suggest use of *toggle actions*.

Hope this provides any help.