# Prevent JSF InputText in allowing multiline text

Tags: java, jsf, trinidad

I used Apache Trinidad Component in rendering my mobile user interface.
Now I have an inputtext code like this but if it for example the space is constrained (browser rendering)
and a carriage return is added in the inputtext

```
<tr:inputText id="it3" simple="true" required="true"
                                maximumLength="30">
    <tr:convertNumber locale="#{myBean.locale}"
                      minFractionDigits="6"
                      maxFractionDigits="6" />
</tr:inputText>
```

..I am getting this error

```
The value must be a number
```

Based on my investigation, it is the carriage return in the inputtext that causes the conversion error

If for example in my inputtext..I have this data (with carriage return..)

```
123456789
01
```

I am getting the error above..

If my data has no carriage return such as this one

```
12345678901
```

then no converter error is received.
Any thoughts?

[Update]
..or better yet. Is there a way for a JSF Input text not to add carriage return or make it single line only?

Comment: Could you use JSTL function to replace the carriage return as in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901875/how-can-i-manipulate-a-string-in-a-jsf-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901875/how-can-i-manipulate-a-string-in-a-jsf-tag)?

Comment: Apparently its not possible as of the moment as we need to stick it out using pure JSF tags..thanks

Comment: I'm confused: are you saying that a html `<input type='text'>` contains carriage returns for you? Because, well, the [HTML reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.value) explicitly says of such values that they are "Any string that contains no line feed (U+000A, “LF”) or carriage return (U+000D, “CR”) characters". Or is trinidad playing tricks on you here by using a `<textarea>` underneath?

Comment: Regular `h:inputText` is single line and doesn't support carriage return inside. How can you put 2 line text inside in your case (via Copy-Paste)?